# Why I get pending from this function

Tags: javascript

```
async function test() {
    const res = await fetch('https://www.easy-mock.com/mock/5c6d317e8d040716434d0a5b/reading/category/homeSmallCategory');
    console.log(res) // data
    return res;
}
console.log(test()) // Promise {<pending>}

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(test()) // Promise {<pending>}
})
```

Please parse it at the `console`.

How do I deal with this problem.I want the data processing in the `test` function .But it always return `Promise {<pending>}`.
And then I think that I can deal with it like this.

```
if (res instanceof Promise) {
    res.then(data => res = data);
}
```

I put it at the end of the `test`.But it still not working.I `console` the `Object.prototype.toString.call(res)`.And then I get `[object Array]`.I realized that inside the `function`. The `res` is an array not matter what.But at the outside the `res` is not alike that. I know this is something about `event loop`.Thanks for your help.

Comment: you have to return a Promise. `return Promise.resolve(res)`

Comment: The async function always returns a promise.

Comment: there is nothing with event loop here, you are just printing a promise, you could `console.log(await test())` if it's all inside a async function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
async function test() {
    const res = await fetch('https://www.easy-mock.com/mock/5c6d317e8d040716434d0a5b/reading/category/homeSmallCategory');
    console.log(res) // data
    return res;
}
console.log(test()) // Promise {<pending>}
```

That's simply because `test` is an `async` method and `async` method always return a `Promise`. So you either chain a `.then` or `await test()`

```js
test().then(res => console.log(res))
```

or

```js
const res = await test();
console.log(res)
```

Comment: If I don't use `async`, is there a way to process the data in a function that required `fetch` and return the correct data.

Comment: @suedar: Yes of course, and I believe you knew the alternatives since you shared this link https://mp.weixin.qq.com/s/WJUwKgtl0uAJJfiU9alL3g on your previous question

Comment: LOL.Okay, Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach.

```js
async function test() {
    const res = await fetch('https://www.easy-mock.com/mock/5c6d317e8d040716434d0a5b/reading/category/homeSmallCategory');
    return res;
}
test().then(ok => {console.log(ok)}, not_ok => {console.log(not_ok)});
```